# How to sense mobile signal coming to a room using arduino uno

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

How to make arduino sense mobile signal coming into a room and display the calling number on an LCD screen

Comment: So is not possible to use arduino to block a specific mobile number coming to a room before it gets to the phone and allowing  others ?

Comment: Use the configurations options of your phone to blacklist that specific number.

Comment: What you can do, if you really want your phone to change behaviour inside a certain room, is to use NFC tags, assuming the phone has an NFC reader: for example attach an NFC sticker on your nightstand, where you would usually put your phone when you sleep, and configure your phone to change profile to "siesta-time" when it touches said tag.
It's equally easy to make it go back to "Home" or "default" or whatever you like, when it unpairs from the NFC tag.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

Mobile phone signals don't respect artificial boundaries like a room's walls.  You can detect the mobile phone signal from the local cell, but you can't narrow it down to "what is talking to a device in this room".

And if you could just intercept the signals and find out who was calling whom there wouldn't be much security, would there? It's all encrypted and locked down - you can't get at that sort of information "from the air".

What you *could* do though, is to have your mobile phone send out the phone number of an incoming call via bluetooth (many hands free kits already use this kind of facility) and have your Arduino receive that information to display it.

Comment: So is not possible to use arduino to block a specific mobile number coming to a room before it gets to the phone and allowing others ?

Comment: Nope. You could jam all the signals in the local area but a) you'd be breaking the law, and b) you'd have people very pi**ed off coming around and smacking you up with baseball bats.